# Apply Focus to tag parent

Tags: html, css

How to apply if `input:focus` then parent `(div)` change color of border?

```css
    div {
      width: 150px;
      height: 26px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: white;
    }
    
    input {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
```

and div must have `border: 1px solid blue;` if `<input>` focused.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osh8dac9/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently no 'parent' tag selector in CSS - see this answer here : [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

The only way to explicitly alter the CSS of the parent `div` when your `input` is in focus would be to use JavaScript.

If you're able to use JavaScript in your solution, I can provide an example.